# After storing a session & echoing it, nothing shows up

Tags: php, session, pdo

I have a form that inserts some things to MySQL database.

Username.
Password.
ID.

I store the username into  a session, and then I change headers (.php?recovery=success).
After that, I want to test if my session worked (For later use, so then I can go to that username's column in the database to fetch the ID we inserted, if I will just do echo $ID, it will generate a new ID.

```
else if (isset($_GET['recovery']) && $_GET['recovery'] == 'success') 
{
echo $_SESSION['user'];

    /* 

    ***REMOVED FOR TESTING***

    $fetch = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ':username' LIMIT 1");
    $fetch->bindValue(':username', $_SESSION['user']);
    $fetch->execute();

    while($row = $fetch->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )) {
        echo $row['recover_id'];
    }
    */
}
```

Problem:

I filled out the form, on submit it took me to recover.php?recovery=success
and then when echoing the session data, there is no output?

I'm requiring the file session.inc.php which opens a new session.

This is the whole code:

http://pastebin.com/ba77rDi3

What am I doing wrong?

I am new to PHP, and specially PDO.
Thanks!

ADDITIONAL:

Session.inc.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

Comment: What's in `session.inc.php`?

Comment: How do you open a new session?

Comment: @John <?php session_start(); ?>

Comment: @purepksorpurepk Are you positive that you are getting into the `else if (isset($_GET['recovery'])` statement? Add `echo 'I'm here!';` or `die('Yes, I'm in the else if');` above `echo $_SESSION['user'];` to debug if you are getting into the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code is storing information into the Session and then redirecting with a call to header (see snippet).

```
                // Let's store these into a session now.
                $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['pass'] = $password;

                //Now let's refresh the page, to a different header.
                header('Location: recover.php?recovery=success');
```

Just to be cautious; I would advise an explicit call to

[session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)

Before your redirect, to ensure that the session data is being properly saved before execution leaves the current page...like so:

```
                    // Let's store these into a session now.
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['pass'] = $password;


                    session_write_close();                       

                    //Now let's refresh the page, to a different header.
                    header('Location: recover.php?recovery=success');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried it, and it doesn't really changes, just doesn't show anything like it used to.

Comment: Also; I just noticed that your FORM element is set to submit it's action via POST.  Unless you are setting GET manually in your URL or I missed a spot in your code where GET is set by PHP before the call to header() you will **never** hit the IF..THEN block you are looking for (i.e. - isset($_GET['recovery']) && $_GET['recovery'] == 'success').

Comment: Ah!  Nevermind I see it; it's directly in the call to header()

Comment: Why? what is the problem with that? Im setting the sessions, and then redirecting to GET recovery=success, out of the code im checking if the page is GET recovery=success, if yes show the session?

Comment: and at the very top, to make sure i do this :  if (!isset($_GET['recovery'])) {

Comment: For purposes of debugging; I suggest replacing echo $_SESSION['user'] with var_dump($_SESSION) - to see what if anything is being placed into the SESSION array.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26816/discussion-between-purepksor-purepk-and-dogoferis)

Answer (score 1):

Problem was:

I put the code inside the statement that checking if recovery is **NOT** set

```
if (!isset($_GET['recovery'])) {
```

at the top of the code, if you didn't see in the pastebin.

I put the code outside of that statement, it it worked.